# Get values of all POST checkboxes in array via PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, post, checkbox

I'm making a form that allows the user to check where they want certain push notifications to go. There is multiple checkboxes that get POSTed in PHP. Here is my PHP snippet:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
function sendMessage(){
    $pushmessage = ($_POST['PushMessage']);
    $content = array(
    "en" => $pushmessage
    );

foreach($_POST['formDeliver'] as $check) {
        $segments = $check; 
    }

$fields = array(
  'app_id' => "app-id-here",
  'included_segments' => array($segments),
  'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
  'contents' => $content
);
```

Edit: Here is my checkbox code:

```
      <input class="LCB" type="checkbox" id="district" value="All" name="formDeliver[]" checked><label class="light" for="district">District-Wide (Everyone)</label><br>
      <input class="LCB" type="checkbox" id="high" value="High School" name="formDeliver[]"><label class="light" for="high">High School</label><br>
      <input class="LCB" type="checkbox" id="middle" value="Middle School" name="formDeliver[]"><label class="light" for="middle">Middle School</label><br>
      <input class="LCB" type="checkbox" id="williams" value="Williams Ave." name="formDeliver[]"><label class="light" for="williams">Williams Ave.</label><br>
      <input class="LCB" type="checkbox" id="norwoodv" value="Norwood View" name="formDeliver[]"><label class="light" for="norwoodv">Norwood View</label><br>
      <input class="LCB" type="checkbox" id="sharpsburg" value="Sharpsburg Elementary" name="formDeliver[]"><label class="light" for="sharpsburg">Sharpsburg Ave.</label><br>
      <input class="LCB" type="checkbox" id="athletics" value="Athletics" name="formDeliver[]"><label class="light" for="athletics">Athletics</label>
```

Whenever the form is submitted, the $fields array submits the message info. I need to pass the segments (values of the checkboxes) as a string like this: "String 1", "String 2", "String 3". Whenever i do this, however, it only grabs the last ticked checkbox and submits it into the $segments variable. Is this something I'm doing wrong or not seeing?

Comment: You're reassigning the variable `$segments` each time through the loop. What do you expect it to do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the `foreach()` you are overwriting the `$segments` variable each time through.  Just use the checkbox array:

**Based on comments you probably want JSON**:

```
'included_segments' => json_encode($_POST['formDeliver']),
```

**For a comma separated list:**

```
'included_segments' => implode(', ', $_POST['formDeliver']),
```

In your current code, this would work but is redundant and not needed:

```
foreach($_POST['formDeliver'] as $check) {
    $segments[] = $check; 
}
$segments = implode(', ', $segments);
//or
$segments = json_encode($segments);
```

Comment: This works, however the values it is passing now look like this: "All\", \"High School\", \"Middle School", etc. How do i remove the forward slashes?

Comment: How would i go about fixing this? I was able to remove the slash marks, however I need my strings to be passed along as an array (Ex. ["String 1", "String 2", "String 3"]). How do i achieve this?

Comment: the JSON. When the output is given it shows like this: ["String 1, String 2, String 3"] but i need it to show like this: ["String 1", "String 2", "String 3"], as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the specific names of each `checkbox`, you can manually create an array that saves `TRUE` if that specific `checkbox` was checked or `FALSE` if it wasn't:

```
$form_checks = [];//creating an array that will save the info obtained

//saving TRUE or FALSE for each specific checkbox
$form_checks['All'] = (isset($_POST['All']))?TRUE:FALSE;
$form_checks['High School'] = (isset($_POST['High School']))?TRUE:FALSE;
$form_checks['Middle School'] = (isset($_POST['Middle School']))?TRUE:FALSE;
$form_checks['Williams Ave.'] = (isset($_POST['Williams Ave.']))?TRUE:FALSE;
$form_checks['Norwood View'] = (isset($_POST['Norwood View']))?TRUE:FALSE;
$form_checks['Sharpsburg Elementary'] = (isset($_POST['Sharpsburg Elementary']))?TRUE:FALSE;
$form_checks['Athletics'] = (isset($_POST['Athletics']))?TRUE:FALSE;

//inserting the result into your $fields array:
$fields = array(
  'app_id' => "app-id-here",
  'included_segments' => $form_checks,
  'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
  'contents' => $content
);
```

If you have an array containing the names of each `checkbox`, you could also create a `foreach` loop to do this for you in a similar fashion. Also if you were not looking for `TRUE` or `FALSE` specifically, you can just change it for any values you prefer, possibly `"CHECKED"` and `"NOT-CHECKED"`.